# Join strings in a list with \n in the list (Python)

Tags: python, string, list

Simple question that I couldn't find on Stack. How do I join strings in a list **with special characters in the list**?

(The dataset indeed contains '/n' instead of the right version of '\n')

For example:

```
sentence = ['lets', 'make', 'a', 'newline', '/n' ,'now we have made a new line']
' '.join(sentence)
```

Current output:

```
>> 'lets make a newline /n now we have made a new line'
```

Ideal output:

```
>>'lets make a newline
now we have made a new line'
```

Comment: `'/n'` is not a new line...make sure you are using `'\n'`. And then actually print it: `print(' '.join(sentence))`

Comment: An extra note to _be careful_ when copying code to ask questions and googling things: you have `/n` in your code and `\n` in the "current output": one of those is obviously wrong.

Comment: The string in the dataset is actually '\n'...not typo... is there a way I still get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't see that `/n` in your ideal output and you have to break it into two lines. So, you can try this

```
sentence = ['lets', 'make', 'a', 'newline', '/n' ,'now we have made a new line'] 
sentence.remove('/n')
sentence.insert(4,'\n')
print(' '.join(sentence))
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you made a typo and typed `/n` instead of `\n`.

Modify your code by changing the slash with `\`

```py
sentence = ['lets', 'make', 'a', 'newline', '\n' ,'now we have made a new line']
print(' '.join(sentence))
```

Comment: Did you intentionally take @Mark's comment and turn it into an answer to get credit?

Comment: The string in the dataset is actually '\n'...not typo... is there a way I still get the desired output?